# Don't evaluate variable in view

Tags: angularjs

I have a site built with AngularJS. I need to put a text somewhere on the page that looks something like this: `Use {{name}} to display the username`.

But AngularJS automatically tries to evaluate `{{name}}`. But in this case I don't want it to be evaluated. I just simply want to show that as a text.

I already tried to use the unicode characters: `&#123;&#123;name&#125;&#125;`. But it still evaluates that...

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [ngNonBindable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable) directive

```
<span ng-non-bindable>Use {{name}} to display the username.</span>
```

Comment: I knew they had to have something. It works, thanks.